# Solving nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can I solve the following differential equation?
$$(x^2+y^2) y''- xy'^3 + yy'^2 -xy' + y = 0.$$
I've also try to solve it by Maple software, but I couldn't.
Can anyone help me to solve it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What exactly is the task, what type of "solving" do you want to achieve? Are there initial values or boundary values?

Comment: $y=x$ is a solution

Comment: No, there is not any initial values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$(x^2+y^2) y''- xy'^3 + yy'^2 -xy' + y = 0.$$
Rewrite it as:
$$(x^2+y^2) y''=(xy'-y)(y'^2+1)$$
$$\dfrac {y''}{y'^2+1}=\left (\dfrac {y}{x} \right)'\dfrac {1}{1+\dfrac {y^2}{x^2}}$$
Integrate to reduce the order.
Note that:
$$(\arctan y')'=\dfrac {y''}{y'^2+1}$$
So that you have:
$$(\arctan y')=\arctan \left (\dfrac {y}{x} \right )+C_1$$

Comment: Thanks, but how can I calculate   y    in order to   x   ? I mean the final answer.

Comment: looks good to me.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici looks hoot to me nice too Claude

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici  Can you tell me what will be the solution curves of your answer? How do you gain “y(x)” finally?

Comment: @geosd I am not sure that you will get an explicit solution for the non linear de you posted. If Mapale gives nothing it's maybe because it's not easy to integrate

Comment: I really appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you for your creative solution.

Comment: You're welcome @geosd

Comment: Thank you @Dinush